# How do companies like facebook release features slowly to portions of their user base?

Tags: agile, production-environment, release-management

I like how facebook releases features incrementally and not all at once to their entire user base. I get that this can be replicated with a bunch if statements smattered all throughout your code, but there needs to be a better way to do this. Perhaps that really is all they are doing, but that seems rather inelegant. Does anyone know if there is an industry standard for an architecture than can incrementally release features to portions of a user base?

On that same note, I have a feeling that all of their employees see an entirely different completely beta view of the site. So it seems that they are able to deem certain portions of their website as beta and others as production and have some sort of access control list to guide what people see? That seems like it would be slow.

Thanks!

Comment: You can actually see http://beta.facebook.com/ yourself - API changes roll out there a week or two before they roll out to everyone.

Comment: Seems like it would be straightforward enough to simply route certain users (by any arbitrary criteria you could imagine) to a different server running a different version of the software.

Comment: I would agree - These guys probably have thousands of servers.  Some clusters run different versions of the frontend, and user accounts can be setup to route to certain clusters of web servers by a load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has a lot of servers so they can apply new features only on some of them. Also they have some servers where they test new features before commiting to the production.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution is, `if` statements and feature flags using systems like [gargoyle (in python).](https://github.com/YPlan/gargoyle)

Using a system like this you could do something like:

```
if feature_flag.is_active(MY_FEATURE_NAME, request, user, other_key_objects):
    # do some stuff
```

In a web interface you would be able to isolate describe users, requests, or any other key object your system has and deliver your feature to them. In fact, via requests you could do things like direct X% of traffic to the new feature, and thus do things like A/B test and gather analytics.

Answer (score 0):

An approach to this is to have a tiered architecture where the authentication tier hands-off to the product tier.

A user enters the product URL and that is resolved to direct them to a cluster of authentication servers. These servers handle authentication and then hand off the session to a cluster of product servers.

Using this approach you can:

- Separate out your product servers in to 'zones' that run different versions of your application
- Run logic on your authentication servers that decides which zone to route the session to

As an example, you could have Zone A running the latest production code and Zone B running beta code. At the point of login the authentication server sends every user with a user name starting with a-m to Zone A and n-z to Zone B. That way roughly half the users are running on the beta product.

Depending on the information you have available at the point of login you could even do something more sophisticated than this. For example you could target a particular user demographic (e.g. age ranges, gender, location, etc).